# How to download the uploaded file in Text Version in Asp.Net MVC 5 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a basic Asp.Net MVC 5 application in c# language. In one of the form User can upload a document. Now I also have link if user clicks the link I want the corresponding document to get downloaded to user's system in **Txt Version**. Kindly guide me on how to achieve this. Below is what I have till now.

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Download", "Resume", new { resumeId = @item.ResumeId})">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Resume.ResumeName)</a>
```

Document Upload :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Candidate")]
    public ActionResult UploadResume(ResumeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (viewModel.UploadedResume != null && viewModel.UploadedResume.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var tempresume = new Resume
                    {
                        FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(viewModel.UploadedResume.FileName),
                        ContentType = viewModel.UploadedResume.ContentType,
                        ResumeName = viewModel.ResumeName,
                        CandidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                        datetime = System.DateTime.Now
                    };
                    using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(viewModel.UploadedResume.InputStream))
                    {
                        tempresume.Content = reader.ReadBytes(viewModel.UploadedResume.ContentLength);
                    }
                    _context.Resumes.Add(tempresume);
                }
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ResumeCenter");
            }
        }
        catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Controller Action: // This should return a Txt Version **********

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "Candidate, Referrer")]
        public FileContentResult Download(int resumeId)
        {
            var temp = _context
                .Resumes.Where(f => f.ResumeId == resumeId).SingleOrDefault();
            var fileRes = new FileContentResult(temp.Content.ToArray(), temp.ContentType);
            fileRes.FileDownloadName = temp.FileName;

            return fileRes;
        }
```

With above code, I just get the original uploaded document format.

Comment: you want some other document type (Ex : word/pdf) to be converted to text document and send that to the user ? Don't think it is that trivial :)

Comment: @Shyju: Yes, sir, so suppose I uploaded pdf, but when I am downloading I wanted it to be in txt format. Is it too involved (code wise)?

Comment: @Shyju: What if when user uploads the document then at that time itself, I convert it to .txt and .pdf and  store copies of it in DB?

Comment: @Shyju: Can you kinldy guide me please..

Comment: I do not think it is that easy to generate a text output from a pdf/word doc (at least in the context of an MVC app). That is why a lot of websites ask you for word format of your result AND text format of your resume. ;)

Comment: Is it easy to have word version of uploaded pdf or vice versa? Or that too is too involved, (forget about the text version)?

Comment: I was going through this web site https://uptowork.com and it has that capability. So, I was just curious.